# Putting a String ArrayList into SQLite Database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, arraylist

I am having trouble getting the entire string put into my arraylist correctly. I am assuming the error has something to do with my custom textwatcher or how I am looping through the array list. Here is my code:

```
      case R.id.action_add:
                Workout workout = new Workout("", "", "", "");
                workoutList.add(workout);

                ListView exerciseList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.exerciseListView);
                CustomAdapter myAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_list, workoutList);
                exerciseList.setAdapter(myAdapter);

                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Workout> {

        private int layoutResource;

        public CustomAdapter(Context context, int layoutResource, List<Workout> workoutList) {
            super(context, layoutResource, workoutList);
            this.layoutResource = layoutResource;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View view = convertView;

            if (view == null) {
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                view = layoutInflater.inflate(layoutResource, null);

            }

            Workout workout = getItem(position);

            if (workout != null) {
                final EditText exercise = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.exercise);
                final EditText reps = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.reps);
                final EditText sets = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.sets);

                if (exercise != null){
                    exercise.addTextChangedListener(new CustomWatcher(exercise));
                }

                if (reps != null) {
                    reps.addTextChangedListener(new CustomWatcher(reps));
                }

                if (sets != null) {
                    sets.addTextChangedListener(new CustomWatcher(sets));
                }
            }

            return view;
        }
    }
    //Textwatcher class
    class CustomWatcher implements TextWatcher {

        private View view;
        public CustomWatcher(View view) {
            this.view = view;
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            String text = editable.toString();
            switch (view.getId()) {

                //exercises
                case R.id.exercise:
                   exercises.add(text);
                    break;
                //reps
                case R.id.reps:
                   reps.add(text);
                    break;
                //sets
                case R.id.sets:
                    sets.add(text);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The cases are buttons. So when I click the add button I am trying to add my custom list view to my page which includes three text views. Then when I click save I am trying to get it to save the data from each edit text position into an array list to store into my data base.

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection for menu
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_save:

                String title = MyWorkoutsActivity.workouts.get(workoutID);
                String ex;
                String rp;
                String st;
                SQLDatabase db = new SQLDatabase(this);
                for(int i = 0; i < workoutList.size(); i++){
                   //exercises, reps, and sets always same number so only one for loop needed
                    ex = exercises.get(i);
                    rp = reps.get(i);
                    st = sets.get(i);
                    db.addExercise(new Workout(title, ex, rp, st));

                }
                List<Workout> workouts = db.getAllExercises();

                for (Workout wo : workouts) {
                    String log = "Workout " + wo.getWorkout() + "Exercise " + wo.getExercise()  + " ,Reps " + wo.getReps() + " ,Sets " + wo.getSets();
                    // Writing workouts to log
                    Log.d("Workout ", log);
                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyWorkoutsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

                return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the listener method afterTextChanged is lunched after the first letter typed in so it will save the first letter into the list and so on 
until you end up with a list of characters.

the solution is : simply don't use the textwatcher because you want to save the data when the user presses the save button so add the data to the exercises list when the button is hit like this code :

```
public void onClick(View view){
    //the exercise and reps and sets are the EditText fields that you have
    exercises.add(exercise.getText());
    exercises.add(reps.getText());
    exercises.add(sets.getText());

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Only problem with that is how would I refer to each listview row separately to add the edit text data? It is not a set amount of rows, there are as many rows as the amount of times the user pressed add new.

Comment: I think this tutorial will help :

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_list_view.htm

this will do the trick for you if you don't want to change the list dynamically (the save button is in a different activity than the listview)